# How to generate a representable ascii character in elm?

Tags: elm

I'm playing around with elm and creating a password generator as a toy exercise. Struggling with generating characters in the ascii 'set' that are "printable". At the moment I'm using the following command:

```
 Random.generate NewRandomChar (Random.Char.ascii))
```

But this creates a lot of non printable characters (e.g. NUL). If instead I used Random.Char.latin I don't get numbers or symbols like exclamation mark so not great for a password generator.
Is there a simple way to get a character in the ascii range dec33 to dec126?

Thank you!

The full code : https://github.com/jumpifzero/snippets/blob/master/experiments/elm/pwd-generator.elm

Edit: 
Just for completeness I've added a simple predicate to check if the character is in the range needed but not loving the solution :/ Any help cleaning this appreciated!
https://github.com/jumpifzero/snippets/blob/master/experiments/elm/pwd-generator2.elm

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `elm-community/random-extra` package, which includes a random character generator between a given range using [`char`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/random-extra/2.0.0/Random-Char#char):

```elm
Random.generate NewRandomChar (Random.Char.char 33 126))
```

You could easily roll your own function without the need for the extra package:

```elm
import Char exposing (fromCode)
import Random exposing (Generator, map, int)

passwordCharGenerator : Generator Char
passwordCharGenerator =
    map fromCode (int 33 126)
```